# Unity 5 Google Cardboard VR SDK Frame Rate

Tags: unity, frame-rate, virtual-reality

I am running the Google Cardboard's official demo which doesn't really have much things on the scene (https://developers.google.com/cardboard/unity/download) on my Personal Unity 5 on my Nexus 5.

The fps is around 40 and I am wondering if the fps is so low because of my Nexus 5's hardware specs or is there a way to optimize the fps in Unity or some configuration in Google Cardboard's SDK?

Comment: Version 0.6 is out. Did you tried with that one? Maybe that helps ;)